# Unable to insert into table after creating an After insert trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have two tables 
Table one: `default_sellers_commissions`  have:

```
id
value - INT
```

Table two:  `marketplace_saleperpartner`  have:

```
id
userID
commission - INT default '0.00'
commission_id
```

what I need is after insert a new row in table `marketplace_saleperpartner` update the `marketplace_saleperpartner.commission` value with value from `default_sellers_commissions.value` where the `marketplace_saleperpartner.commission_id` = `default_sellers_commissions.id`

So I create a `trigger` :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `marketplacedefaultcommission`
AFTER INSERT ON `marketplace_saleperpartner`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE marketplace_saleperpartner
SET `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`commision` = `default_sellers_commissions`.`value`
WHERE `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`comm_id` = `default_sellers_commissions`.`id`
AND `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`commision`='0.00';
```

P.S:
for some reason I need the  `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`commision` to insert for the first time with `value='0.00'`

now I am getting this error while trying to insert a new row into table `marketplace_saleperpartner`

```
MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying `marketplace_saleperpartner.`, say `NEW.` (or `OLD.`, if appropriate).